# CPQ Quote not synchronized with Opportunity when Primary checkbox is updated

Tags: apex, opportunity, cpq, quote

I have a custom QLE done by LWC, at the beginning of the year we used to uncheck the SBQQ__Primary__c checkbox if it was Primary, wait, and then check it again (with a flow) to trigger the synchronization from the CPQ Quote with the opportunity. But now it does not work, even if we are on the quote record page and uncheck/check the field, it does not work.
Is there an update that avoids that process? Or a new way to activate that sync when the user clicks a button, like updating a field in the quote or opportunity?

Thanks!